# C++ concept of ownership, compared to .net

Tags: c++, .net, memory-management, coding-style, c++-concepts

What follows is a series of conclusions I've drawn from the currently available knowledge on the topic, and the question is essentially whether this is correct and if not, what is the appropriate correction to these conclusions.

As an experienced .net developer, I am totally formed into the idea that all object instances exist almost as particles in a cloud, and object membership simply interrelates those particles. When a particle or particle cloud cannot be linked by some reference back to the root object in the framework, it or its members are disposed of. This essentially the result of reference counting and some kind of network analysis maintaining an understanding of whether an object still has a path to the root.

In this structure, an identifiable instance of an object can be referenced ('owned') by many other objects and the network of ownership can be as complex and circular/self-referential as necessary.

It appears in transitioning to C++ that this freedom must be constrained for the benefit of memory management. All objects must have a clear tree of ownership, with object lifetime maintained by its parent.

Lifetime may also be constrained by scope as for temporary values within braced code sections {}. Lifetime can also, though it is absolutely to be avoided, by using the `new` keyword and careful use of `delete`

In newer standardisations of C++ that things like shared_ptr appear to be designed to allow something closer to the .net managed memory model. I do not know if these also offer the same benefit of the managed memory of discarding self-referential but otherwise unconnected object clouds.

An example is the std::list. So far as I can tell, the recommended strategy is that an object instance in the list must be, without the benefit of the shared_ptr constructs, owned solely by the list and have its lifetime dictated by the list's own lifetime. This leads to the need for copy constructors, destructors called on temporaries, or the use of the emplace methods that require the list have a single concrete type. Alternative solutions involve storing pointers to objects and managing object lifetime elsewhere, though this is fraught with obvious dangers. All this seems quite awkward.

In .net a list can reference an object without having to be it's parent or guardian because the object's lifetime is otherwise managed.

I know there are distinctions between heap and stack memory that have implications on performance, however I am not intimately knowledgeable on the topic.

Is my view of the two systems essentially correct? If not, what corrections can be offered? If it is essentially correct, what literature exists that describes the mental model of C++ I need to adopt to create large, powerful and high-performance applications? That includes best-practices for the code as well as the more abstract concept of managing a large application robustly.

Answer (score 3):

In (non-garbage collected) C++, the idea is that memory management is done through destructors, and not some garbage collector. The main advantages of this are:

(1) It's very precise. The language makes very strong guarantees about exactly when and in what order destructors will be called and memory will be freed.

(2) It's simple, transparent and totally portable, with truly minimal overhead. Rather than relying on some opaque garbage collection mechanism which might do things whenever it pleases, you know exactly how the memory management is going to work on every system you compile for. And if you aren't sure when / if things are being freed, you can put debugging output in the destructors and check it out. It's true that modern garbage collectors are really pretty good and only very rarely cause issues, but if you ever actually had an issue with one and needed to debug one you would know that it can be pretty time-consuming and painful.

> I know there are distinctions between heap and stack memory that have implications on performance, however I am not intimately knowledgeable on the topic.

The heap and stack are just exactly what they were in C. The basic idea of the stack is, it's a block of memory which stores the function callstack for the program. The stack is laid out as a series of "stack frames". When a function is called, a pointer is pushed which tells where we should return to when we return later. All the arguments to the function call are placed in succession on the stack. There's also a counter / pointer which indicates how large this stack frame is. When a function is called a new stack frame goes on, when the function returns we pop it. Local variables of functions are also allocated on the stack. The stack has a fixed size and if you exceed it (usually by infinite recursion) you crash with a stack overflow error. Everything that goes on the stack has to have a fixed size known at compile time. This is determined by the "sizeof" operator. If you want to have e.g. a dynamic array, you have to use the "heap", which permits memory to be allocated when the size is only known at run-time, and things can be destroyed in arbitrary order.

The advantage of the stack is that memory allocation is basically instant (the stack frame pointer is just moved) and deallocation happens in a very comfortable way. (When we return from the function and the local vars go out of scope, we simply pop from the stack to free their memory.) C++ makes a very strong guarantee about stack-allocated objects and destructors. The guarantee is that the destructors will always be called, in the reverse order of creation, when the function returns, and also even if it throws an exception instead of returning normally. Essentially, unless your program is terminated abnormally (`std::terminate()`, or `throw 42`), or unless some unusual things happen (some special cases in which your destructors themselves throw exceptions, but basically you should never do this, because it is asking for trouble), destructors of the automatic objects will be called at a very particular point in time, in a very particular order. If they have member variables with constructors / destructors, then those get called also in a particular order. If inheritance is involved... you can read about it if you aren't familiar.

Basically this is a very powerful and rigorous mechanism that you can use to control all kinds of resources -- not just memory, but things like sockets, connections to printers, pointers to C library instances which must be "closed", anything which is a shared resource which is exclusive, or something which must be cleaned up in a certain way when it is no longer needed.

Not everything can go on the stack. For instance, if you have a dynamically sized array, it can't go on the stack, it has to go on the heap, the same way as is commonly taught in C. (Because, only things of sizes known to the compiler can go on the stack.) When you put things on the heap though, (using operator new in C++) it has to be paired with a call to delete or the memory doesn't get freed and the destructor doesn't get called.

In C++ the preferred way to manage that is to leverage the power of the stack. Instead of manually calling delete yourself, you use a stack-allocated object whose destructor calls delete. The simplest example is "std::unique_ptr" (aka boost::scoped_ptr). The shared_ptr you mentioned also does something like this. All the C++ standard containers, like vector, list, map, etc. also do this.

IMO this is pattern is basically the gospel of C++. In a well-written C++ program, not only all memory, but all *resources* are managed this way, being released by destructors. This is the very important *RAII* idiom: "Resource Acquisition is Initialization". You can read more about it here: http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?ResourceAcquisitionIsInitialization

In many programs, all of the objects have only one owner, and the object ownership diagram is a tree. In this case everything can be stack-allocated / member variables of stack-allocated, and then all of the memory is on and is managed by the stack. In some cases, objects need to have shared ownership -- the ownership diagram is a DAG (directed acyclic graph). Then you can use shared_ptr for the shared objects. They will be allocated on the heap, but it will work automatically and memory will be managed without you having to do anything more. In the most complex cases, there are cyclic references, cycles in the ownership graph. If you use only shared_ptr in that case then the cycles don't get freed. That's the case that garbage collectors supposedly "do the hard work" for you. In modern C++ the preferred way is to still use shared_ptr in most places, but at at least one link of any cycle, you use a weak_ptr instead, so that the cycle "is broken" and can be freed automatically. This is rarely ever necessary and when it is, it's really not that much work. It's just an alternative engineering style to the automatic garbage collection of many other languages.

Comment: Great response Chris, probably the last paragraph had the most weight for my need. I think in my .net software engineering career I've been happily treating all ownership in the way of the DAG without giving it much thought. It's is an extremely flexible way of solving real problems. That seems to be the logical sticking point. C++ programming have been formed in the sequential programming mold, coming up with very rigorous ways of managing memory through a linear lifetime, pushing ownership up the tree only as far as persistence requires. Would you agree?

Comment: Nice answer, +1. "Throw 42" :)

Answer (score 1):

Your description *works*, but looks somewhat odd, because it essentially tries to define the *object lifetime* concept as the concept of *object* is the same for both ISO C++ and .net.

In fact ... it's not. So your analysis works for that *subpart* of C++ that deals with heap based objects, while C++ is a bit more.

In .net, things like `int`, or `double` are not properly objects (they are called values, and treated as object only if *boxed*).

.net (and C#) does a neat distiction between *value classes* (struct-s) and *reference classes*.

consider

```
b=a; a.val+=2;
```

What's the value of `b.val`?

The concept of value / refeence, in C++ is not related to the concept of class. The only entanglement is when run-time polymorphism is involved.

`std::list<int>` as well as `std::list<persons>` work the same. the int-s and the person-s are owned solely by the list because they are conceptually *members* of it.

```
person a("john"), b("dave");
a = b;
b.name="robert";
```

actually will let a.name to remain "dave".

```
std::list<shared_ptr<person> >
```

is another story: the list owns the ptr that in turn own the person. The policy of list (exclusive owner) apply to the pointers whose policy (sharing) applies to persons.

To match a similar sematics than java, or c#, you should come to a sematica trick like

```
class person_ { ... };
typedef std::shared_ptr<person_> person;

std::list<person> ...
```

Now this is like working with a reference class (apart using -> instead of .) do `aperson->name = "..."` and all the references of that person will see the new name.

Note also that *shared_ptr* are just reference counting pointers. Circular references are NOT discarded. There is no pointer-network that a background process that tries to follow to discover unreachabilities. C++ does not have any garbage collector.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive response. If I could try to summarise your response: 1) the ownership 'policy' of an object's members is flexible in c++ and is not a fundamental trait of the language/compiler; 2) Assignment in c++ is generally by deep copy rather than 'by reference' in the managed languages; 3) shared pointers attempt to reintroduce managed memory semantics into native c++.     I am confused by your example with "john" and "dave", It seems that even if assignment by deep copy is assumed, a.name should be "dave".

Comment: OOPS - sorry, I meant "dave", my mistake. The point is that it will NOT BE "robert".